# Trying to scrape info from a table with multiple pages but can only get the results from the first

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am trying to scrape flight info from https://www.flightstats.com/v2/flight-tracker/departures/LHR/

I am using selenium to load the page a click the necessary buttons such as "close cookie" and select the "hide codeshares". I am able to scrape the first page but not the subsequent ones. I use selenium and a while loop to click next page whilst pagenumber < lastpage to present the data but i am unable to scrape it.

I have tried looking at the network/xhr to see if any additional requests are made when clicking through the pages and i didnt see any, also the url does not change.

Thank you in advance!
Any help is greatly appreciated.

to clarify, it is the time_frame_scrape() function that handles clicking through the pages and scraping the information. The table div and class_ name remain the same whist moving through the pagination but the scraper doesnt scrape the info past the 1st page.

````
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select


info = []
def get_table_info():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/jamie/Desktop/chromedriver")
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get('https://www.flightstats.com/v2/flight-tracker/departures/LHR/')
    time.sleep(2)

    # disable cookie alert
    python_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="onetrust-close-btn-container"]/button')
    python_button.click() #click x button
    time.sleep(2)


    # Get button and click it
    python_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="__next"]/div/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div')
    python_button.click() #click hide codeshare
    time.sleep(1)

    # handover from selenium to BS
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features="lxml")

    num_pages_fetch = soup.find('div', class_='pagination__PaginationContainer-sc-1515b5x-0 dUhdWi').text
    num_pages = int(num_pages_fetch[-3])
    print(num_pages_fetch)
    print(type(num_pages))
    print(num_pages)

# select the next timeframe to scrape
    next_time_frame = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="__next"]/div/section/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/select'))
    next_time_frame.select_by_visible_text("06:00-12:00")
    time.sleep(1)
    refine_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="__next"]/div/section/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/button/span')
    refine_button.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    
    def click_next():
        next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="__next"]/div/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[12]/span')
        next_page.click()
    


    # Scraping every page within selected timeframe
    def time_frame_scrape():
        counter = 0
        while counter <= num_pages:
            table = soup.find('div', class_='table__TableContainer-sc-1x7nv9w-5 fOHnRO')
            for item in table:
                h2_headings = item.find_all('h2')
                for h in h2_headings[1:]:
                    info.append(h.string)
                    print(info)
                
                click_next()
                table = soup.find('div', class_='table__TableContainer-sc-1x7nv9w-5 fOHnRO')
                time.sleep(2)
                counter += 1

        # first element wasnt retrieved from above so this line gets the first element/flight number  
        first = table.find('h2').text
        info.insert(0, first)

    time_frame_scrape()
    ```
````

Comment: can you post minimal code and only the part where you are having problem

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Hi, yeah i'll copy the problem part and edit the orginal post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a less complex solution, and an order of magnitude faster, to retrieve the data you're looking for:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd


df_list = []
r = requests.get('https://www.flightstats.com/v2/flight-tracker/departures/LHR/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
scripts = soup.select('script')

for x in scripts:
    if '__NEXT_DATA__ = ' in x.text:
        json_string = x.text.split('__NEXT_DATA__ = ')[1].split('module={}')[0].strip()
        json_flight_obj = json.loads(json_string)
        actual_flights = json_flight_obj['props']['initialState']['flightTracker']['route']['flights']
        for flight in actual_flights:
            departureTime = flight['departureTime']['time24']
            arrivalTime = flight['arrivalTime']['time24']
            carrier = flight['carrier']['name']
            flightNumber = flight['carrier']['flightNumber']
            operatedBy = flight['operatedBy']
            url = flight['url']
            airport_fs = flight['airport']['fs']
            airport_city = flight['airport']['city']
            df_list.append((departureTime, arrivalTime, carrier, flightNumber, operatedBy, url, airport_fs, airport_city))

df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns = ['departureTime', 'arrivalTime', 'carrier', 'flightNumber', 'operatedBy', 'url', 'airport_fs', 'airport_city'])
df
```

This returns a dataframe with 735 rows × 8 columns:

```
departureTime   arrivalTime carrier flightNumber    operatedBy  url airport_fs  airport_city
0   14:25   17:15   American Airlines   91  None    /flight-tracker/AA/91?year=2022&month=7&date=25&flightId=1102208979 ORD Chicago
1   14:25   17:15   Finnair 5789    Operated by American Airlines 91    /flight-tracker/AY/5789?year=2022&month=7&date=25&flightId=1102208979   ORD Chicago
2   14:25   17:15   British Airways 1546    Operated by American Airlines 91    /flight-tracker/BA/1546?year=2022&month=7&date=25&flightId=1102208979   ORD Chicago
3   14:25   17:15   Gulf Air    4128    Operated by American Airlines 91    /flight-tracker/GF/4128?year=2022&month=7&date=25&flightId=1102208979   ORD Chicago
4   14:25   17:15   Iberia  4396    Operated by American Airlines 91    /flight-tracker/IB/4396?year=2022&month=7&date=25&flightId=1102208979   ORD Chicago
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I dont think I would have ever come up with such an elegent solution and you were right, it improves the speed dramatically. 

Is there a way to eliminate the duplicate entries. In your results you will see there are multiple flights to chicargo but i only really need to know if there is 1 flight and the rest are not important. 

I have looked to see if the script in sources gets changed when i select the "hide codeshares" and it doesnt. 

I am thinking maybe an if statement within the for loop to check if city is the same then skip?

Thanks you again!!!